# Disable permission from react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I disable an already granted permission from android inside a react native application? I did not find any information about it, one answer that I found was disable from settings, but it does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Once a permission has been granted then only way to revoke it is via the settings. I do not believe that it can be done programmatically.  It is possible to grant and revoke permissions using adb but I don't think that is what you are looking for.