# React native: Right way to enable/disable location permission from app

Tags: react-native, location, android-permissions

I am having a toggle button in the app (attached screenshot) where user can enable/disable location access permission for the app? I can request location access permission as follows but how to perform cancel request programmatically

```
           try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
              {
                'title': 'My App',
                'message': 'Allow App to access your location'
              }
            )
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
              this.setState({locationEnabled: true})
            } else {
              this.setState({locationEnabled: false})
            }
          } catch (err) {
             console.warn(err)
          }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Here's another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638977/disable-permission-from-react-native